# cannot sync gradle when adding "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" for Firebase Database

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-2.3

I'm new to Android app development on Android Studio 2.3.3. I'm following the Firebase Database guidelines to connect to the DB. But it fails when doing the Sync (see below error). Many as I are asking the same question, but the solutions seems to be too specific to their own gradle files, so I was able to use it to fix my app. any help will be appreciated :-)

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.lenovo.hereandthere'
```

build.gradle (Project: HereAndThere)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lenovo.hereandthere"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

note:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRjva.jpg)

Comment: add google json service file

Comment: Hi Shubham, which files, where and how to?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file You need a google service json file to use google service plugin

Comment: it was already done. I've uploaded a screenshot about the file : "google-services.json"

Comment: check in the file is the package name is com.example.lenovo.hereandthere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No matching client found for package name 'com.example.lenovo.hereandthere'**

The problem can occur because of one of the following reason:

1. there is no google service .json file is present
2. or google service .json file is present but placed at the wrong location. [check out this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file)
3. or package name is different from the one mentioned in the google service .json (People usually don't do that, but unfortunately this
   is your case.)

Comment: YES, THANK YOU! I recreated a new project with the right package name. I can now read and write to the database. it was such a pain.